# strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, strpos

I'm getting this warning on my upload function and I just can't figure out why. I've looked at other questions of the same error but cannot get a solution.

```
function upload($name,$old,$dir=NULL,$autoid,$number)
{
    global $def_dir;
    if(!$dir)$dir="../".$GLOBALS["logo"];


    if($_FILES[$name]['name']){
        if( is_file($dir.$old) ) unlink($dir.$old);
        $ext=substr($_FILES[$name]['name'],strpos($_FILES[$name]['name'],$name),strlen($_FILES[$name]['name']));
        $file=$autoid.'_'.$number.$ext;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'],$dir.$file);

    }else{
        $file=$old;
    }

    return($file);
}
```

I've tried `var_dump($_FILES[$name]['name']`
and the result was `string(24) "generic-project-icon.png"`

I've tried `print_r($_FILES[$name]['name'])` and the result was `generic-project-icon.png`

am I being blind or is there no array there?

I just cannot figure out why this is happening.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does $name look like when you print_r it?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw the result is the file name:  generic-project-icon.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. function signature `($name,$old,$dir=NULL,$autoid,$number)` parameters with default value move to end `($name,$old,$autoid,$number,$dir=NULL)`
2. try don't use `global` variables pass them as parameter

And answer your question `$_FILES[$name]['name']` can be array when you upload multiple files. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#example-386)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't sure how many files are coming, you can auto-cast the data as an array and loop them.  If there is only a string, then it will become a single element array and loop just once.  [Technique Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d88deb3ca9f9b5ab4ecf026e10abd602d534fa30)

See inline comments...

Code (untested):

```
function upload($name,$old,$autoid,$dir=NULL,$number=1){  // move parameters with default values to the end 
    // remove global variable, it is unused/pointless
    if(!$dir)$dir="../".$GLOBALS["logo"];

    if(isset($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'])){  // check that the element isset()
        foreach((array)$_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'] as $n){  // loop all elements
            if( is_file($dir.$old) ) unlink($dir.$old);
            $file=$autoid.'_'.$number.strstr($name, '.');  // use strstr() to get "dot & extension"
            move_uploaded_file($n,$dir.$file);
         }
    }else{
        $file=$old;
    }

    return($file);
}
```